reading ANTD table multi filter values
I'd like to log the table's filter values.
when filter value is single loging is easy but when it's more than one, it logs only last one.
How can I log all of the filter values?
<Column ~ onFilter={(value, record) => console.log(value)} />

Please clarify the question with debugging details and provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
